# Import multiple flat files in the same folder to SQL Server using flat file name as table name

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file

I have been searching for an efficient way of uploading 100's of text files in the same folder to an SQL Server with one click of a button. I perform this every month, manually mapping the tables. It takes some time to manually choose each flat file (.txt) and map it to the correct loading table before the exact extract.

I have searched many different ways, including SSIS. These are too manual and take too much time to perform and especially maintain.

I have had an idea that, for example below of 5 flat files in the same folder:

1. Extract_ABC.txt
2. Extract_YMCA.txt
3. Extract_WSS.txt
4. Extract_RMC.txt
5. Extract_HBO.txt

To be uploaded to the SQL server in a schema [upload] with their respective file names. The final output would look like this.

1. [servername].[upload].Extract_ABC
2. [servername].[upload].Extract_YMCA
3. [servername].[upload].Extract_WSS
4. [servername].[upload].Extract_RMC
5. [servername].[upload].Extract_HBO

These tables could then be assigned location manually in a lookup table and inserted into the correct tables. This would remove almost all manual work aside from maintaining a location table in the Server.

**Note it is essential that these tables are also created when inserted as the files have unique names when extracted. Also, to note the files are pipe (`|`) delimited text files rather than CSV**.

Does anyone know of a way this can be performed? It would have to avoid the use of Visual Studio manual packages etc. Rather a bulk insert of every flat file into an SQL Server with their respective file names.

An efficient query/process could save me days. Also a **HUGE** plus if this can be run server-side at schedule times to prevent uploads from an actual active pc i.e., SQL Server Agents, etc.

Comment: Powershell could likely be very useful here. You could easily iterate through the files and use `sqlcmd` or `bcp` to import the data into the relevant tables.

Comment: Check this answer, it is not the same case but i think it can help you thinking out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781017/how-to-map-input-and-output-columns-dynamically-in-ssis

Comment: Side question, are your tables *really* all called `txt` and are on a *schema* with the file's (base)name? That is a terrible naming convention if so...

Comment: @Larnu no that was just the example. The files are actually extracted from SAP and have extract and variant numbers. Each of these extracts have a loading and lookup table (pre-processing needs performed on the raw data)

Comment: @Larnu Correct though I will remove the .txt from the output table didn't mean that

Comment: Do files have different column sets i.e. number/type of column data?

Comment: @Alex yes they all have a different number columns and names. Although as they are loading tables and need pre-processed each column is set to a max length of 255 for every file so data types etc are not applicable

Comment: Can you clarify the loading/processing stages? From what I can understand you import files first, storing data into varchar( 255 ) columns and then you run pre-processing steps? Are these steps the same for each file? At what stage if any do you do data type conversions?

Comment: @Alex I import files loading data into varchar (255 columns) selecting each extracts exact loading table each time. I then run pre-processing scripts on each of the loading tables moving them to a lookup table. I will be able to manage the moving to the correct tables for pre-processing. The problem I am looking to solve is to mass import 100's of text files in the same server using their file name as the table name. Once this is created I can proceed from there using a mapping table based on filenames. Thanks!

Comment: Just use @Larnu 's suggestion (Powershell script), then you can even run it as part of SQL Job or Windows scheduled task. You can also implement the entire process using tSQL but it is clunky and bad practice security wise.

Comment: If you (now) need to `CREATE` the tables as well, how do you know what the definition of said tables needs to be? Do your files have accompanying format files? How do *you* know what data types the columns in the new table should have?

Answer (score 3):

In this answer, I will try to give some information and to provide a working example of importing several flat files with different metadata into separate SQL Server tables.

### SSIS limitation

Since SSIS [requires fixed metadata of the data source and destination](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-the-vs_needsnewmetadata-ssis-exception/), I suggest using a C# code rather than automating the SSIS package creation. If SSIS is required, you should use a Script Task to achieve that task.

In similar cases, I generally use C# or another scripting language such as python.

### Why should you not automate the SSIS package generation?

Importing more than 100 flat files to more than 100 tables that should be created at runtime (with no fixed structure) requires creating more than 100 SSIS packages. Even if this process is automated using one of the [SSIS automation tools](https://medium.com/munchy-bytes/automating-ssis-package-creation-manageddts-vs-ezapi-vs-biml-vs-etlgen-d0dca92bf416), it is hard to manage and debug a high number of SSIS packages.

### Unified SQL Server destination table?

If the destination tables structures mostly have similar structures, it is better to import all flat files into a unified SQL Server destination using a schema mapping approach, you can refer to the following answer:

- [How to Map Input and Output Columns dynamically in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781017/how-to-map-input-and-output-columns-dynamically-in-ssis)

### Solution overview

*All code provided in this solution can be improved, but it was written as a prototype*

#### Reading flat-file

I created a class `TextImport` that tries to loop over all flat files within a given directory, read the flat-files metadata and store each file data within a `System.Data.DataTable` object. *(Note that `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly should be added as a reference to use the `TextFieldParser` class)*

```cs
TextImport txtimp = new TextImport(filename, true, 0); // TextImport(string filename, bool containsHeader, int RowsToSkip)
txtimp.BuildDataTableStructure(); //Read flat file metadata
DataTable dt = txtimp.FillDataTable(); //Convert the flat file to a DataTable object
```

The `TextImport` class tries to detect the file metadata *(number of columns, delimiter, text qualifiers, encodings)* based on the first 8 lines *(arbitrary number)* in the flat file.

#### Creating SQL destination table

Then this `System.Data.DataTable` is passed to another class called `SQLExport` that generates and executes a `CREATE TABLE` statement based on the `DataTable` metadata.

```cs
SQLExport.CreateDestinationTable(DataTable dt);
```

#### Inserting data into SQL

Finally, two insert methods are provided:

1. Generate a `INSERT INTO () ... VALUES (),(),()...` statement and execute it to insert data into SQL destination
2. Using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` class to insert data using `BULK INSERT` method.

The main code should look like the following:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //You should set your database connection string
    string connectionstring = @"Data Source=.\SQLINSTANCE;Initial Catalog=tempdb;integrated security=SSPI;";
    //This is the schema of the destination table
    string Schema = "upload";
    //You should set the text files directory
    string directory = @"E:\TextFiles";
    using (SQLExport sqlExp = new SQLExport(connectionstring, Schema))
    {
        //if you don't want to traverse subfolders use System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly
        foreach (string filename in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory,
            "*.txt",System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)){

            using(TextImport txtimp = new TextImport(filename, true, 0))
            {
                txtimp.BuildDataTableStructure();
                DataTable dt = txtimp.FillDataTable();
                dt.TableName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);
                sqlExp.CreateDestinationTable(dt);
                //Insert using BULK INSERT
                sqlExp.InsertUsingSQLBulk(dt);
                        
                //Creates and Execute an INSERT INTO statment 
                //sqlExp.InsertIntoDb(dt);
            }
        }            
    }

}
```

#### Test

I tested this solution on two flat files stored on [the following link](https://www.flyrnai.org/compleat/ExampleFiles.jsp) *(the first result of my Google search)*, as shown in the screenshots below, tables are created successfully, and data is inserted.

*Note that all columns are created a `NVARCHAR(255)`, you can change this within the `SQLExport.cs` file*

[image]

[image]

You can check the complete code in the following GitHub repository *(.NET Framework 4.6.1 C# console application)*:

- [GitHub - TextToSQL](https://github.com/HadiFadl/TextToSQL)

*If you decided to use a Script Task to run this code, you should only copy the classes from the GitHub project into your Script Task project Remember to add `Microsoft.VisualBasic` as a reference.*

### How to run a C# console application from an SQL Server Agent Job?

You can simply edit the C# Console application to pass the connection string and text files directory as arguments, then run it using a `cmdExec` job step:

- [Microsoft Docs - Create a CmdExec Job Step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-cmdexec-job-step?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Run a C# Console Application from SQL Server Agent (Job)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691408/run-a-c-sharp-console-application-from-sql-server-agent-job)
- [sql job to run every certain time and execute a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266561/sql-job-to-run-every-certain-time-and-execute-a-console-application)

Or even by using an SSIS package:

- [Executing your own .NET console application from SSIS](https://www.sqlshack.com/executing-net-console-application-ssis/)

### Alternative - using Task Scheduler

Another alternative is to use Windows Task Scheduler to periodically run the C# console application.

- [Setup A Task Scheduler To Run Application Periodically In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setup-task-scheduler-to-run-application/)
- [Console Application Using Windows Scheduler](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/)

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned, I would actually use something like Powershell to do this. The script to do so is actually quite simple.

```sh
#Below is a Linux Path, as I am running SQL Server (and Powershell) on Linux
$ImportFolder = "/home/mssql/ImportSample" #The Folder your files are in
$Instance = "." #The Instance you are inserting the data into. "." means local host
$Database = "ImportSample" #The database you are inserting the data into

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportFolder -Filter "*.txt" #Get all the txt files

#Loop the files
foreach($File in $Files){
    #Create the statement
    $SQL = "BULK INSERT dbo.[$($File.BaseName.Replace("]","]]"))] FROM '$($File.FullName.Replace("'","''"))' WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV', FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', FIRSTROW = 2);"

    Write-Debug $SQL

    #Execute the statement
    Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $Database -Query $SQL
}
```

This assumes Windows Authentication, however, if you are using SQL Authentication you can pass the `-Username` and `-Password` switches to `Invoke-SqlCmd`.

---

*Note: This answer was written before the necessity to `CREATE` the tables was added. This does not meet the new requirement, however, I am leaving the answer here as it may still prove useful to others with a question similar to the original version of this question, without said requirement.*

Comment: Would this method work with a pipe delimited text field instead of a CSV?

Comment: Just change the parameters of the `BULK INSERT` appropriately for your terminators, @pandasman . So you can see I state a comma (`,`) for the field terminator, and a line feed (`0x0a`) for the row terminator. I *do* assume you're using SQL Server 2017+ mind. Though provided you aren't using quote identifiers, then you could just remove the `FORMAT` for older versions.

Comment: I am being returned an error message saying : Invalid object name 'the actual file name' (without .txt). This doesn't seem to be working. I will post the full error below. The error shows for two extracts in the same folder

Comment: Invoke-SqlCmd : Invalid object name 'dbo.000088_000007'.
At line:15 char:5
+     Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $Database -Quer ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Invoke-SqlCmd : Invalid object name 'dbo.000089_000003'.
At line:15 char:5
+     Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $Database -Quer ...
+

Comment: *"Invalid object name 'dbo.000088_00000'"* The error is telling you the problem. The table doesn't exist. It was *assumed* that the tables exist, and it's implied in your question.

Comment: Yes I see that, but the tables will never exist in the database as the ID's will always be unique. The idea is it will upload to fresh table with the file name. Thanks!

Comment: Then no, this won't work. Like I said, it was implied the tables already existed. There was no talk of you needing to `CREATE` the tables as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I added asynchronous code to be run in console application Core3.1 or later at the bottom.

I kind of took this as a challenge to see if I could do it. Here is what I came up with in c#...

Basic concept:

1. Loop through files
2. Read each file into a data table using pipe(|) as delimeter
3. Read header row into string List
4. Create a table based on headers all of data type varchar(255)
5. Load Data table into new table using Bulk Copy.

   ```
    public static string cstr = "Enter your connection string to destination here";

    //if you are going to use script task inside SSIS then this is what goes into whatever the Main is in SSIS.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dir = @"C:\whereever";

        foreach(var file in new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles().AsEnumerable().Where(f=>f.Extension.Contains("txt")))
        {
            DataTable dt = ConvertCSVtoDataTable(file.FullName, '|');
            //getColumnNames into an object
            List<string> colNames = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                colNames.Add(dc.ColumnName);

            //create table
            string tableName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
            createTable(colNames, tableName);
            //load table
            loadDtIntoDb(dt, colNames, tableName);
        }
    }

    public static void loadDtIntoDb(DataTable dt, List<string> cols, string tableName)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cstr))
        {
            using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                bcp.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                foreach (var col in cols)
                    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(col, col);
                conn.Open();
                bcp.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void createTable(List<string> dcs,string tableName)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Create table {0}(", tableName));
        foreach (var dc in dcs)
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} varchar(255),", dc));
        //Clean sql by removing final ',' and adding a close paren 
        string sql = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',') + ")";
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cstr))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    public static DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string strFilePath, char delim)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath))
        {
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(delim);
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(header);
            }
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(delim);
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
   ```

Here is a list of my using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
```

I see you are looking for efficiency. Here is how to do it asynchronously:

```
public static string cstr = "Enter your connection string to destination here";

 //This cannot be done in SSIS
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {
     var dir = @"C:\whereever";
 
     var files = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles().AsEnumerable().Where(f=>f.Extension.Contains("txt")))
     await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(async f=> await processFile(f)));
  }

 public statis async Task processFile(File file)
 {
     DataTable dt = await ConvertCSVtoDataTable(file.FullName, '|');
     //getColumnNames into an object
     List<string> colNames = new List<string>();
     foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
         colNames.Add(dc.ColumnName);

     //create table
     string tableName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
     await createTable(colNames, tableName);
     //load table
     await loadDtIntoDb(dt, colNames, tableName);
 }



public static async Task loadDtIntoDb(DataTable dt, List<string> cols, string tableName)
 {
     using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cstr))
     {
         using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
         {
             bcp.DestinationTableName = tableName;
             foreach (var col in cols)
                 bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(col, col);
             conn.Open();
             await bcp.WriteToServerAsync(dt);
         }
     }
 }

 public static async Task createTable(List<string> dcs,string tableName)
 {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Create table {0}(", tableName));
     foreach (var dc in dcs)
         sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} varchar(255),", dc));
     //Clean sql by removing final ',' and adding a close paren 
     string sql = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',') + ")";
     using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cstr))
     {
         using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
         {
             conn.Open();
             await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
         }
     }
 

 public static async Task<DataTable> ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string strFilePath, char delim)
 {
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath))
     {
         string[] headers = await sr.ReadLineAsync().Split(delim);
         foreach (string header in headers)
         {
             dt.Columns.Add(header);
         }
         while (!sr.EndOfStream)
         {
             string[] rows = await sr.ReadLineAsync().Split(delim);
             DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
             for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
             {
                 dr[i] = rows[i];
             }
             dt.Rows.Add(dr);
         }
     }
     return dt;
 }
```

Comment: You can easily make this asynchronous but not inside SSIS so I left it in this format.

Comment: Note: this is written net5.0 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is a Nuget, if using SSIS you will need to reference System.Data.SqlClient instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted this as a new answer, rather than editing my existing one, as the my original answer answers the original question.

Saying that, this answer simply expands on the existing answer. Unfortunately no details were given on what the data types of the data in the table should be, so I have ***assumed*** that all data will be an `nvarchar(200)`. You can change that in the dynamic statement, however, note this solution assumes ***all*** data has the same data type. If this isn't true, and you need strongly typed data, it's time to ask a new question ([don't be a chameleon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal)).

---

Anyway, as I said, this expands on the existing answer from me. You'll note an additional section of code, this handles the creation of the table, dynamically.

I create a temporary table (which would be limited to the scope of the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` is it created in), to `INSERT` the first row from your file, which I **assume** has the headers. For the field terminator, I use a character I *assume* won't appear in your data, a pipe (`|`). If they can, use a different character. I then *only* `INSERT` the first row (hence `FIRSTROW` and `LASTROW` but having the value `1`). This `INSERT`s the first row from the file as a delimited value.

Next I create a dynamic statement and split that value up into rows, and reaggregate, but quoting the field names, and defining the data type (`nvarchar(200)`). You will need to use a string splitter that respects ordinal positions here, **NOT** `STRING_SPLIT`. I use `DelimitedSplitN4K_LEAD` (which is located in my `Utility` database), and its definition can be found [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2).

Finally that dynamic statement is executed, created the table with the column names in the right order, all with the data type `nvarchar(200)`. The `Invoke-Sqlcmd` then executes that statement.

Then we go back to the original solution, and `BULK INSERT` the data.

```sh
$ImportFolder = "/home/mssql/ImportSample" #The Folder your files are in
$Instance = "." #The Instance you are inserting the data into. "." means local host
$Database = "ImportSample" #The database you are inserting the data into

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportFolder -Filter "*.txt" #Get all the txt files

#Loop the files
foreach($File in $Files){
    #Create the creation statement
    Write-Verbose "Defining table creation script for $($File.Name)."
    $CreateSQL = "CREATE TABLE #Rows (DelimitedData nvarchar(4000));`n" +
                 "BULK INSERT #Rows FROM '$($File.FullName.Replace("'","''"))' WITH(FORMAT = 'CSV', FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', FIRSTROW = 1, LASTROW = 1);`n" + 
                 "DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);`n" +
                 "SELECT @SQL = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.[$($File.BaseName.Replace("]","]]"))] (' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(DSL.Item) + N' nvarchar(200)',N',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DSL.ItemNumber) + N');' FROM #Rows R CROSS APPLY Utility.fn.DelimitedSplitN4K_LEAD(R.DelimitedData,N',') DSL;`n" + 
                 "EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;"
    
    #Execute the statement
    Write-Verbose "Table creation script for $($File.Name) generated:"
    Write-Verbose $CreateSQL
    Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $Database -Query $CreateSQL -Username $User -Password $Password
    
    #Create the Insert statement
    Write-Verbose "Defining BULK INSERT script for $($File.Name)."
    $InsertSQL = "BULK INSERT dbo.[$($File.BaseName.Replace("]","]]"))] FROM '$($File.FullName.Replace("'","''"))' WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV', FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', FIRSTROW = 2);"

    Write-Verbose "BULK INSERT script for $($File.Name) generated:"
    Write-Verbose $InsertSQL

    #Execute the statement
    Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $Database -Query $InsertSQL -Username $User -Password $Password
}
```

Couple of screenshots demonstrating this working (as can't be demonstrated with a fiddle):
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stored procedure that uses a dynamic script to:

1. `BULK INSERT` the file into table `[My_bulk_insert_data]` assuming that the first line of the file contains the column names:
2. Then bulk insert using a dynamic script taking into account the column names

```sql
create proc usp_bulkinsert_file(@fullfilename as nvarchar(max))

as
begin
   

declare @filename as nvarchar(max)
set @filename = substring(@fullfilename,1 + LEN(@fullfilename) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@fullfilename)) + 1, len(@fullfilename))

declare @script as nvarchar(max)
if exists(select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'My_bulk_insert_data') drop table My_bulk_insert_data
set @script = 'if exists(select 1 from sysobjects where name =''' + @filename + ''') drop table [' + @filename + ']'
exec(@script)

create table My_bulk_insert_data(data nvarchar(max))

set @script='
BULK INSERT dbo.My_bulk_insert_data
FROM ''' + @fullfilename + '''
WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ''''
) 
'
print @script

exec(@script)

declare @data as nvarchar(max)
select top 1 @data = data from My_bulk_insert_data



set @script = 'Create Table [' + @filename + ']('
select @script = @script + '[' + value + ']' + ' nvarchar(max) ,' from string_split(@data, '|') My_bulk_insert_data

set @script = SUBSTRING(@script, 1, len(@script) - 1) + ')'

print @script

exec(@script)

set @script='BULK INSERT [' + @filename + ']' + ' from ''' + @fullfilename + '''
with
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''
)
' 
print @script
exec(@script)

end
```

*Results Screenshot*

[image]

Comment: Even if I think that using a script language approach gives more flexibility, I liked doing that with dynamic SQL. +1