# Import multiple pipe delimited text flat files in the same folder to SQL Server with different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, t-sql, etl

This is a question similar to a previous question I have asked here :

 [Import multiple flat files in the same folder to SQL Server using flat file name as table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695001/import-multiple-flat-files-in-the-same-folder-to-sql-server-using-flat-file-name) 
but much more tailored and detailed [(don't be a chameleon)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal)

## The Question

The aim of this question is to find efficient way to load in **over 200 pipe ( | ) delimited text files**  at the same time (on a regular basis and over night).
Each text file has a different number of columns and column names.
All of the text files are stored in the same folder with their name associated with their assigned table name and table extract ID ie: **Extract_MachineTypes_1**.

Using a Power Shell script looks to be the best option. I have made multiple attempts connecting to my server and using BULK INSERT but to no avail. I will attach my latest attempt at the bottom of this post.
Each table can be uploaded to the server with the column type nvarchar(255) as they will be processed after the fact at a later time.

Running the final script via an SQL Agent would be the best resolve for scheduled running, hence calling the Powershell script require setting up also.

### Sample Data

MachineType_1

| MachineType | No. | LongName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Alongname |
| b | 2 | blongname |
| c | 3 | clongname |
| d | 4 | dlongname |
| e | 5 | elongname |

MachineType_2

| MachineType | No. | LongName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f | 6 | flongname |
| g | 7 | glongname |
| h | 8 | hlongname |
| i | 9 | ilongname |
| j | 10 | jlongname |

Animal Type

| Animal ype | Friendly with | LongName | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | 1 | Donkey | words |
| Bat | 2 | N/A | more words |
| Cat | 3 | Dog | less words |
| Donkey | 4 | No-one | test? |
| Elephant | 5 | Mice | sof |

### Expected Output

The expected output of this would be two tables loaded into the server with type nvarchar(255) with the table names  **MachineType (10 entries)**  and  **AnimalType (5 entries)**

### My attempt

```
 $ImportFolder = "location\"
$Instance = "servername" t
$Database = "dbname" #The database you are inserting the data into
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportFolder -Filter "*.txt" 
#Loop the files
foreach($File in $Files){
    #Create the creation statement
    Write-Verbose "Defining table creation script for $($File.Name)."
    $CreateSQL = "CREATE TABLE #Rows (DelimitedData nvarchar(255));`n" +
                 "BULK INSERT #Rows FROM '$($File.FullName.Replace("'","''"))' WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', FIRSTROW = 1, LASTROW = 1);`n" + 
                 "DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);`n" +
                 "SELECT @SQL = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.[$($File.BaseName.Replace("]","]]"))] (' + N' nvarchar(255)',N',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DSL.ItemNumber) + N');' FROM #Rows R CROSS APPLY Utility.fn.DelimitedSplitN4K_LEAD(R.DelimitedData,N',') DSL;`n" + 
                 "EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;"
    #Execute the statement
    Write-Verbose "Table creation script for $($File.Name) generated:"
    Write-Verbose $CreateSQL
    Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $Database -Query $CreateSQL
    #Create the Insert statement
    Write-Verbose "Defining BULK INSERT script for $($File.Name)."
    $InsertSQL = "BULK INSERT dbo.[$($File.BaseName.Replace("]","]]"))] FROM '$($File.FullName.Replace("'","''"))' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', FIRSTROW = 2);"
    Write-Verbose "BULK INSERT script for $($File.Name) generated:"
    Write-Verbose $InsertSQL
    #Execute the statement
    Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $Database -Query $InsertSQL
}'
```

Current errors:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd : A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
At PowerSheel Auto Upload Script.ps1:20 char:5
+     Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $Database -Quer ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
 
Invoke-SqlCmd : Invalid object name 'dbo.file'.
At PowerSheel Auto Upload Script.ps1:30 char:5
+     Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $Database -Quer ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Any help on this would be great!

Ideally an SQL Server Job that can be run on a schedule that runs a PS script within a select folder to upload multiple files is the best fit for this problem.

Comment: Maybe use `bcp`? Or an SSIS automated job?

Comment: A SSIS automated job would require script to upload the data if I am correct. The SSIS job could be used to upload at scheduled times though yes

Comment: SSIS is built for this kind of thing. You don't need a script task. However, you would need to create 200 data flows which is a bit of a pain to do via the graphical IDE. SSIS data flows can also be constructed [programatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-programming-overview?view=sql-server-ver16). But if the total data volume is small, and since you're doing no transforms, SSIS might be overkill, in which case I agree with BCP. Schedule via SQL agent, windows task scheduler, etc... whatever is normal for your current environment.

Comment: The files coming in are constantly changing in table names and columns so the idea is that it is not fixed but dynamic and uploads the files easily every time. BCP doesn't work for uploading on my end. At the minute I upload each file manually file Import and Export in SQL Server.

Comment: @trenton-ftw it is a question. I am asking of a way to perform what I am asking. I have suggested a method I have already tried and evidenced my failed attempt - this is something I have been stuck on for a long time now. If you have nothing nice to say don't say it.

Comment: @pandasman If the question is, can this be done via a PowerShell script started from within a SQL Server Job? The answer is yes.  I believe everyone who commented advised that is not a good option for this and there are many better options out there. So helping answer your question as is, is just a case of solving the problem using the wrong solution. So they would be evil x2. Simply writing code for others (not the purpose of SO), and solving a problem that should never have been presented in the first place.